# Website jumps horizontally

Tags: html, css

just a small HTML/CSS question:

[This Website](http://www.orthopaede-fuerth.de/index.html) jumps horizontally when you navigate to "Leistungen". I isolate the problem: It occurs only, when there is content in

```html
<div id="box1">  and  <div id="box2">
```

But I only use `<h3>`, `<ul>` and `<li>` so I cannot find mistakes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Jumps horizontally? Sounds like your website is too long which creates a scrollbar?

Comment: this page to same problem "ZON Nürnberg" create scrollbar

Comment: Or use: html {
overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; 
overflow-y: scroll;
}

Comment: What the hell means "jumps horizontally" ? With Firefox and 1366px resolution I can't see anything wrong. In responsive mode it works fine. What is your real problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just want to make sure the scrollbar is always visible (this is the only "jump" I can see). To fix this you can add the following to your CSS:

```
html {
       overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

This will ensure the scrollbar is always there, so there shouldn't be a jump.

Answer (score 0):

Your page only moves when going from "Arzte" to "Leistungen" and thats because its adding the scrollbar because there is lots of content on "Leistungen" and not much on "Artze". Is that what you mean?

Comment: Maybe someone thinks that this is better in a comment than in an answer. But I don't know. Downvoter, show your face!

Comment: But it is the answer. He asked why and I told him. As per my other comment he could turn on scrollbars all the time.

Comment: It wasn't me either, but I can see that it sort of reads like a comment than a full clear answer. At least it's not -1 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is off-topic, as the question was about the scroll-bar not wrapping, as it turns out. I will leave the answer here for now as it can resolve this problem as an alternative to the scroll bar.

As far as I can tell, the problem is that there is nothing in the css to make your "box1", "box2", etc. objects wrap, so when you zoom in so the right-most picture goes beyond the edge of the screen. You can fix the problem by adding a display: inline-block; property to the css.

This is the bit of CSS regarding these objects in your main.css:

```
#mycontainer p
{
    font-size: 0.75em;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}


#box1
{
    margin-right: 1em; margin-bottom: 5em;
}
#box2
{
    margin-right: 1em; margin-bottom: 5em;
}
#box3
{
    margin-right: 1em; margin-bottom: 5em;
}
#box4
{
    margin-right: 1em; margin-bottom: 5em;
}
```

There is nothing in here to make the boxes wrap. You can accomplish the desired effect using display: inline-block with something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.img_box
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21; 
    display: inline-block;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Boxes</h2>

<div class="img_box">Floating box</div>
<div class="img_box">Floating box</div>
<div class="img_box">Floating box</div>
<div class="img_box">Floating box</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the fiddle, so you can see how it works: https://fiddle.jshell.net/m67zftfk/

Basically, just give your #box1, #box2, #box3, #box4 a `display: inline-block;` and `width: some_width; height: some_height; margin: some_margin;` in the css.

inline-block makes the element inline but also allows for height and width which allows wrapping: when the elements go beyond the screen edged, the browser wraps them. You need to supply size parameters for it to work, though.

Comment: Well, that was not my question, but it would be really nice to make that work, too (for mobile phones and so on). So I added "display: inline-block;" to my #Box1 but it does not work.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I will leave the answer here, in case there is someone who needs wrapping and not a scroll bar.

Comment: I have expanded upon the answer a bit. Try supplying width and height to boxes explicitly and they should wrap. Unfortunately, it's difficult for me to do a proper test without reproducing your entire setup.

Comment: Do you have any other ideas? I tested it (not longer online anymore), but it has not worked. Even not with weight and height.